# java.time.Clock in java 1.8 gives unexpected time value

Tags: java, time, timezone

I read that the time API is much better in java 1.8, so I decided to use it in my application. I try to get current date & time to be able to compare times(sth like `after()` or `before()` in Date class) but when I type this code:

```
java.time.Clock clock = java.time.Clock.system(ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw"));
System.out.println(clock.instant().toString());
```

I get the time that is 2 hours before the current time.
**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3):

Clock.instant() gives you an Instant which lacks time zone information. This means when you call Instant.toString(), the output will be in UTC. Since Europe is on Daylight Savings time at the moment, you are two hours ahead of this.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now(clock)` or more directly `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw"))` will create a more suitable object.

Comment: Thanks for answer but in documentation of the Clock class we can see "A clock providing access to the current instant, date and time using a time-zone." So why it lacks time-zone information?

Comment: Clock.instant() is no instance of Clock, but one of Instant. Instant is a specific point in time, no more and no less. Conceptionally, it's the same as the old java.util.Date class (with the addition that it's immutable and thread-safe). For localized times (including timezones), turn to LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime.